# custom message error jquery validate

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I need to custom eror message in my client side validation like this (i'm using mvc client side validation)

```
  define([
    'jquery',
    'validate',
    'unobtrusive'
], function ($, validator, unobtrusive) {
    jQuery.validator.addMethod('firstnamevalidator',
                        function (value, element, params) {
                            if(value<parms.min)
                             **show message error1**
                             if(value==parms.min)
                             **show message error 2**
                            return false;
                        });

    jQuery.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add('firstnamevalidator',
                             ['min'],
                             function (options) {
                                 options.rules['firstnamevalidator'] = {
                                     min: options.params.min                                 };
                                 options.messages['firstnamevalidator'] = options.message;
                             });
});
```

How can i show message1 ou message2 in the validation??

regards

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I cannot test this but I believe, looking at the code, that what you want to do needs to be done when you add the adapters. Basically the "method" you add should only return true or false.

When this method returns false, all the chain to find the message to display is activated and if the message is a function, it will be called with the parameters and the element as arguments:

```
options.messages['firstnamevalidator'] = function (params, elem) {
    // logic here... you can use options.message of course...
}
```

Sadly it seems you won't be able to get the value without actually getting it from the element using something like: `$(elem).val()`.

I hope this take you in the right direction.

What is the exact problem you are trying to solve? There may be a simpler way.

Comment: i need to cusom error message when the value< min, i show message1 when value>max show error2 when value==0 message3 etc...

Comment: I can't do his when i add the adapter because the logic is in the addmethod